# Javascript reduce function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I have an array as follows:

```
[[1,1],[2,8],[3,12],[4,13],[5,23],[6,30],[7,41],[8,44],[9,50]]
```

So lets say it is the format of `[[x,y]]`

As you can see the above array, the first element inside inner arrays goes from `1,2...6` which is **x**, and the second element of inner arrays are `1,8,12,13,23 and 30` which is **y**.
This is a cumulative array of **y** and I want to convert it into non-cumulative but with a twist.

I want to convert **y** to non-cumulative array by getting the difference from the value of **y** at last 3rd value of **x**

Therefore I want the final result to be as follows:

```
[[1,1],[2,8],[3,0],[4,1],[5,11],[6,0],[7,11],[8,14],[9,0]]
```

I have tried a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gxytx6ka/1/

So far I have been able to get the difference between two array elements by some help of Dekel (stackoverflow guy) as you can see in the above fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var old_arr = [ [1, 1], [2, 8], [3, 12], [4, 13], [5, 23], [6, 30], [7, 41], [8, 44], [9, 50] ];
  var new_arr = old_arr.reduce(function(a, b, c, d) {
    if (a.length) {
      a.push([d[c][0], d[c][1] - d[c - 1][1]])
    } else {
      a = [b]
    }
    return a;
  }, []);

  console.log(new_arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

which outputs:

```
[[1,1],[2,7],[3,4],[4,1],[5,10],[6,7],[7,11],[8,3],[9,6]]
```

but I want:

```
[[1,1],[2,8],[3,0],[4,1],[5,11],[6,0],[7,11],[8,14],[9,0]]
```

which I am not able to get.

I tried using `a%3==0` in if condition, but not working...
Basically I want the final output in an efficient way.

Comment: Why are the **y** cumulative ? I don't get the logic between the initial array and the result

Comment: First `a` is an array. Second, have you tried `(c+1)%3 === 0`?

Comment: @Rajesh it is giving me `[[8,44],[9,6]]`.
@Weedoze: It comes cumulative from backend, I want to do this calculation in javascript

Comment: 50-44 is 6 (for position 9). By what logic is that supposed to be 0?

Comment: @torazaburo I want to calculate difference from every 3rd...

Comment: @user1735921 Could you please provide more information ? What is the logic ?

Comment: I still don't understand what "every 3rd" means

Comment: @Rajesh If you understood the logic could you please update the question ? or explain it here ?

Comment: Please explain **exactly** where the `0` in `[9,0]` comes from. Please provide an arithmetic expression for calculating that, such as `an = a(n-3)`.

Comment: @Weedoze I partially understand it. Pattern is to get difference between current and previous values, but for every third element, value of y must be 0

Comment: @Rajesh I still dont get the logic ahah Anyway someone understood it

Comment: @Weedoze its unclear but I guess georg nailed it

Comment: Shouldn't be `[5,11]` instead of `[5,10]`?

Comment: Using this function: `f=a=>a.map((x,i)=>x.map((m,n)=>n?x[0]%3?m-t:(t=m)&&0:m),t=0);` you can do `output = f(input)`;

Comment: @Guedes, yeah it should be 5,11. Edited. I already got the answer though, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which returns simply an array with the result.

```js
var array = [[1,1], [2,8], [3,12], [4,13], [5,23], [6,30], [7,41], [8,44], [9,50]],
    result = array.map(function (a, i) {
        (i + 1) % 3 || (this.last = a[1]);
        return [a[0], a[1] - this.last];
    }, { last: 0 });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var array = [[1,1], [2,8], [3,12], [4,13], [5,23], [6,30], [7,41], [8,44], [9,50]],
    result = array.map((l => ([x, y], i) => (++i % 3 || (l = y), [x, y - l]))(0));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice solution with good use of the comma-operator, @NinaScholz!

Comment: @trincot, looks a bit golfed. ;)

Comment: I had never seen `.as-console-wrapper` before, nice to know :) ... +1 anyways

Comment: Your first solution compiles successfully in ExecJS. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Why `reduce`? A simple loop does the job perfectly fine:

```js
let a = [[1,1],[2,8],[3,12],[4,13],[5,23],[6,30],[7,41],[8,44],[9,50]];

let out = [],
    n = 0,
    lastY = 0;

for (let [x, y] of a) {
    if (++n % 3 == 0)
        lastY = y;
    out.push([x, y - lastY]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(out))
```

Comment: As you seems to be the only one who understood the logic, could you please add it to your answer thus everyone can correctly understand the question and answer ?

Comment: Because I thought that reduce would be faster ?

Comment: `reduce` is not by definition faster -- although it can be. Reasons for using `reduce` are more often related to the coding style you prefer, and *functional programming* addicts love it. But it you want to go for speed, you'll often (not always) get a slight performance improvement with `for` loops.

Comment: @user1735921: `reduce` is slower and severely hurts readability. No reason to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

With `reduce` you can do it like this (also using ES6 arrow function and spread operator):

```js
var arr = [[1,1], [2,8], [3,12], [4,13], [5,23], [6,30], [7,41], [8,44], [9,50]];

var result = arr.reduce( ([arr, v], [x, y], i) =>
      [[...arr,[x, i%3==2 ? 0 : y-v]], i%3==2 ? y : v], [[],0])[0];

console.log(result);
```

#### Explanation

`reduce` is called with a double initial value (a pair):

```
[[],0]
```

The first element is the array that will accumulate into the final result, and the second value is the current value to which subsequent `y` values will be offset.

These two values are captured by the argument `[arr, v]` which is a destructuring assignment (ES6). The `reduce` callback will always return a new pair like that, with extended `arr` and (potentially) updated `v`.

The callback function also takes the current `[x, y]` pair from the original array. Again this is a destructuring assignment, so you have direct access to `x` and `y` variables. The third argument `i` is the current, zero-based index in the original array.

As said, the callback returns a pair. The first element in that pair is constructed as follows:

```
[...arr, [x, i%3==2 ? 0 : y-v]]
```

The `...arr` notation spreads the previously collected result elements as a list, and one pair is added to that list: `[x, i%3==2 ? 0 : y-v]`. The `x` is just reproduced from the original `[x, y]`, but the `y` follows the requested logic with the ternary operator: if we are at an index that has a remainder of 2 when divided by 3, then the `y` value should be 0. Otherwise, it should be offset against the previously set value `v`.

The second element in the pair, must be the new value for `v`:

```
i%3==2 ? y : v
```

Again, according to the requested logic, `v` remains unchanged when the remainder is not 2, but otherwise it is set to the current value of `y`.

So `reduce` will thus accumulate/update these two values in each iteration, and finally return a pair, of which only the first has our interest, which is why there is `[0]` at the end.

#### Notes

As you seemed to be looking for a `reduce` implementation, that is what I went with, but whenever your output array has just as many elements as your input array (like is the case here) you can also consider to use `map` as a good alternative (See answer that NinaScholz posted).

If you are open for a less *functional programming* way, you can also choose to use a `for` loop and maybe gain a bit of performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with reduce — You just need to figure out when to zero-out every third value and when to find the difference between the current value and it's previous (third) value.

Naming parameters with more intelligible names also helps out.

```js
var old_arr = [ [1, 1], [2, 8], [3, 12], [4, 13], [5, 23], [6, 30], [7, 41], [8, 44], [9, 50] ];
var new_arr = old_arr.reduce(function(result, value, index, arr) {
  if (index % 3 == 2) {
    return result.concat([[value[0], 0]]); // Set every third value to 0.
  } else {
    var prevIndex = index - (index % 3) - 1;
    var prevVal = prevIndex > -1 ? arr[prevIndex][1] : 0;
    return result.concat([[value[0], Math.abs(prevVal - value[1])]]);
  }
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(new_arr)); // [[1,1],[2,8],[3,0],[4,1],[5,10],[6,0],[7,11],[8,3],[9,0]]
```